# For Brushless DC Motors would one expect harmonics to be different between Delta and Y stator windings?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, harmonics, winding

Given two 3-phase brushless DC motors with the only difference being that one is wound delta, the other Y with center grounded, would I expect to see high frequency voltage-current harmonics to be significantly different between the two?

So in each case the measured terminal to terminal phase resistance and inductance would be the same, the number of poles and PM magnet geometry would be the same,the effective torque constants would be the same, the frame size would be the same, and the drive would be the same.

Realizing of course that making all these other factors the 'same' is a hypothetical situation, and may not be physically realizable.

Answer (score 1):

Delta BLDC motors tend to require higher currents but lower voltages and are generally used for higher speed applications. Wye BLDC motors require lower currents but higher voltages.

I would suspect that Delta BLDCs suffer from higher circulating currents.

Comment: Sorry I was actually interested whether the delta winding vs a Y winding is different enough in the geometry to result in different high frequency harmonics. I'll update my question to clarify that.