# For induction motors, would one expect harmonics to be different between Delta and Y stator windings?

Tags: three-phase, induction-motor, harmonics

Given two induction motors with the only difference being that one is wound delta, the other Y, would I expect to see a different behavior if the source is a three phase voltage with harmonics?

Comment: C'mon, what is the obvious one - at least try to make a fist of answering your own question so anyone reading it believes it isn't homework or they are trying to teach an infant the art of brain-surgery.

Comment: The obvious one is the fact that the voltage on the stator winding is bigger in the case of a star connection while the current is bigger in the case of a delta configuration.

Comment: I think you have this partly back to front in terms of an advantage.

Comment: Another one is that the homopolar harmonics of the three phase voltage source doesn't influence the motor in a star configuration while they do in a delta configuration. But I'm not sure.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm studying induction motors right now, so I can have very dumb questions, I know. It isn't an homework, it's a doubt that I have.

Comment: @Andyaka It's the same question [asked before](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/313149/for-brushless-dc-motors-would-one-expect-harmonics-to-be-different-between-delta?rq=1) not by me but for induction motors.

Comment: Here's the deal - your question realistically encourages opinion and potentially debate and that is not what EE.SE is about. It's a question and answer site. You ask a straightforward question (hopefully) and you get at least one reasonably good answer.

Comment: @Andyaka Is it better in this way?

Comment: It is better like this for sure. Have you heard about starting a motor in star then when up to speed throwing switches that put it in delta. There is a reason behind this and quite often the reverse is true especially if you want high torque at start up.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, I've heard of that and it should be due to the change of amplitude of current and voltage in the stator winding. I start the induction motor with a star configuration to have a bigger current that means bigger torque (and less speed) and than I shift to delta configuration to have bigger a bigger voltage that means bigger speed (and less torque). Is it correct?

Comment: @gvgramazio Not an expert, but I seem to remember that delta connected have null triplen harmonics. If I am wrong, please let me know, so I'd correct the mistake.

Comment: @Andyaka, but other than this, there are other differences or this is the only one? I thought of behavior with respect to the harmonics, in particular the homopolar ones should disappear in the case of a star configuration.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen, Yes, in general a star connected balanced load without the _star center_ (sorry but I don't know if this is the right term in english) connected to ground doesn't have harmonics multiple of 3.

Comment: @gvgramazio So it was the wye (star) connection. Could this be a partial answer to your own question?

Comment: Well, I already know that. I wanted to know if there are other differences or not. Also, I don't know if the harmonics multiple of 3 disappear in an induction motor or due to the fact that it's an active load is not true.

Comment: “[…] would one expect harmonics to be different […]” // “[…] if the source is a three phase voltage with harmonics?“ // The line voltages (and hence the phase voltages) of the delta stator won’t have triplen harmonics (only non-triplen odd harmonics) because KVL would be violated. The line voltages of the wye stator won’t have triplen harmonics because KVL would be violated, but the phase voltage can have triplen harmonics. I explained this in more details in **[this Quora answer](https://bit.ly/36lK47F)** (the link is too long so I shortened it using Bitly).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the motor mechanical kW is the same, with a delta winding, non-triplen odd order harmonics will circulate in the windings, adding heat to the motor. So for the same amount of mechanical output, the motor will consume a little more electrical kW.

Comment: And in Y don't we have non-triplen odd order harmonics? Seems very strange to me.

Comment: Yes, but they don't circulate INSIDE of the motor causing additional heating.

Comment: Sorry, I reformulate my sentence. I think that one of the difference between Y and delta winding is that in Y winding 3rd harmonic of the current and its multiple don't circulate while they do in delta winding.